# Spring Boot IMAP Channel Adapter is losing emails while processing a large number of inbound emails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a working Spring boot application which is processing emails from a dedicated mailbox. Everything works well in the test environment when the number of emails is limited. In Production environment, these emails are getting generated by a scheduled job and sometimes there are more than 10000 emails in one batch. Each email has some big attachments which the application is parsing and storing.
This is where the application is slowing down badly and in the worst case scenarios losing the emails as well. Looks like a case of thread starvation as the process is resource intensive.
Is there a way to optimize this flow?

My email config is as below. Service Activator snippet is from another service to handle the email message.

```
    @Bean
    public QueueChannel emailReceiveChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel(100);
    }

    @Bean(name = "emailPoller")
    public PollerMetadata poller() {
        PollerMetadata poller = new PollerMetadata();
        poller.setReceiveTimeout(0);
        poller.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(2000));
        poller.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(100);
        poller.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        
        return poller;
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "emailTaskExecutor")
    public AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ImapIdleChannelAdapter mailAdapter() {
        
        ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapAdapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(imapMailReceiver());
        imapAdapter.setAutoStartup(true);
        imapAdapter.setOutputChannel(emailReceiveChannel());
        
        return imapAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver() {

        StringBuilder impaURI = new StringBuilder();
        impaURI.append(MAIL_PROTOCOL).append("://").append(MAIL_USERNAME).append(":").append(MAIL_PASSWORD)
        .append("@").append(MAIL_HOST).append(":").append(MAIL_PORT).append("/").append(MAIL_FOLDER);
        
        logger.info("IMAP URL = " + impaURI.toString());
        
        ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(impaURI.toString());
        mailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(true);
        mailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
        mailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties());
        mailReceiver.setAutoCloseFolder(false);

        return mailReceiver;
    }
     
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "emailReceiveChannel", poller = @Poller(value = "emailPoller"))
    public void handleMessage(final Message message) {
        
        logger.info("Email Message received on " + LocalDate.now());
        if (message != null && message instanceof MimeMessage) {
            /*
             * Delegate the message handling to another thread and release this one.
             */
            processEmailMessage(message);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Global Task scheduler
     */
    @Bean(name = "taskScheduler")
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(100);
        return scheduler;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to consider to increase `TaskScheduler` thread pool: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler.

You also may consider do not use that `emailReceiveChannel` as a queue. The `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` is async by nature and already does its logic within scheduled thread.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I already have configured the Taskscheduler in my application as per the link provided. Updated the code above. I hope configuring a global task scheduler will have the same effect if I assign a task scheduler directly to IMAP Adapter

Comment: Correct, same result going to be. As I said: consider to not let it to pull too many messages. They eats memory and GC time.

Comment: Hi Artem, With QueueChannel at least all the Messages are getting processed even though it is taking a lot of time to process, 13000 emails in a batch. But when I am using a direct channel instead of Queue channel, mails are getting lost and nothing is in the logs as well. I have reduced the message per poll from 100 to 5