# Is there a way to route the emails (read via an imap idle adaptor) to different output channel based on the size of the email?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have configured an Imap Idle adaptor which is listening to an email box, reading and parsing the email. The handling of these emails is done in a service activator class.
These emails are getting generated in bulk from an ERP system and have heavy attachments. Because of the heavy load, some emails are getting lost.
Is there a way in Spring integration to route these emails to different output channels based on the size and assign different handler classes to these output channels so that these emails can be processed in parallel and bulky emails don't block the processing?

[Details of the configuration is in this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878451/spring-boot-imap-channel-adapter-is-losing-emails-while-processing-a-large-numbe)

Answer (score 0):

The `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` produces a `MimeMessage` if you don't let it to convert the email into a simple content.

That `MimeMessage` has this method to check from your router:

```
/**
 * Return the size of the content of this message in bytes. 
 * Return -1 if the size cannot be determined. <p>
 *
 * Note that this number may not be an exact measure of the
 * content size and may or may not account for any transfer
 * encoding of the content. <p>
 *
 * This implementation returns the size of the <code>content</code>
 * array (if not null), or, if <code>contentStream</code> is not
 * null, and the <code>available</code> method returns a positive
 * number, it returns that number as the size.  Otherwise, it returns
 * -1.
 *
 * @return          size of content in bytes
 * @exception   MessagingException for failures
 */  
@Override
public int getSize() throws MessagingException {
```

See router for more info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#messaging-routing-chapter

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers